# Damaged Anti-reflective Layer on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

My MacBook Pro's display has the anti-reflective coating damaged. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has recently renewed replacing screens for the following MacBooks:
MacBook Pro (13“, early 2013)
MacBook Pro (15“, early 2013)
MacBook Pro (13“, late 2013)
MacBook Pro (15“, late 2013)
MacBook Pro (13“, mid 2014)
MacBook Pro (15“, mid 2014)
MacBook Pro (13“, early 2015)
MacBook Pro (15“, mid 2015)
MacBook Pro (13“, 2016)
MacBook Pro (15“, 2016)
MacBook Pro (13“, 2017)
MacBook Pro (15“, 2017)
MacBook (12“, early 2015)
MacBook (12“, early 2016)
MacBook (12“, early 2017)
even after warranty has ended for free! Just head on over to the nearest Apple Store or a certified Apple Service Provider and get a new screen.